# Get above element id

Tags: jquery

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" class="box_1"></textarea>
<div class="buttons">
  <img src="smileys/smile.gif" title=":)" />
</div>
```

How to get the id of the textarea when the image is clicked? There are more than one .buttons and smileys on the page (as well as more than one textarea).

Comment: so you want to get the id of the textarea that lies immediately above the container of the img ?

Comment: try `$(this).closest("textarea").prop("id");`

Comment: `.closest('textarea')` won't work because the `img` is not nested within it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div.buttons img').click(function(){
   var id = $(this.parentNode).prev('textarea').prop('id');       
   // var id = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.id;       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4DWU/1/

Answer (score 1):

You get it by navigating the dom tree:

```
function imgClicked(){
    var theElementId = $(this).parent().prev().prop("id");
}
```

Comment: jQuery object doesn't have `previous` method.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, I corrected my answer, this should do it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [jQuery 1.7+](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you might want to do this with the `.on()` method:

```
$('div.buttons').on('click', 'img', function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().prev('textarea').prop('id');
    // doSomething with the id
});
```

If you aren't loading content dynamically, it's no big deal to bind the `img`'s `click()` directly, however.